# Servo is making extra cycle

Tags: python-3.x, arduino

I've got two Python scripts that changes position of two servos. The second script works as desired but when I run the first one the first servo makes an extra cycle or spin which is a problem. Can you see why is that happening ?
(this is just added text to pass character-length check on SO)

First script:

```
from pyfirmata import ArduinoMega, SERVO
from time import sleep

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
board = ArduinoMega(port)
sleep(5)

board.digital[13].mode = SERVO
board.digital[12].mode = SERVO

def set_first_servo(angle):
    board.digital[13].write(angle)
    sleep(0.015)

def set_second_servo(angle):
    board.digital[12].write(angle)
    sleep(0.015)

a, b = True, True
while a:
    for position in range(135, 0, -1):
        set_first_servo(position)

    a = False

while b:
    for position in range(0, 135):
        set_second_servo(position)

    b = False

board.exit()
```

And second script (no problem with this one):

```
from pyfirmata import ArduinoMega, SERVO
from time import sleep

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
board = ArduinoMega(port)
sleep(5)

board.digital[13].mode = SERVO
board.digital[12].mode = SERVO

def set_first_servo(angle):
    board.digital[13].write(angle)
    sleep(0.015)

def set_second_servo(angle):
    board.digital[12].write(angle)
    sleep(0.015)

c, d = True, True

while c:
    for position in range(0, b):
        set_first_servo(position)
    c = False

while d:
    for position in range(e, 0, -1):
        set_second_servo(position)

    d = False

board.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to flip flop the (135, 0, -1) and the (0, 135).

```
from pyfirmata import ArduinoMega, SERVO
from time import sleep

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
board = ArduinoMega(port)
sleep(5)

board.digital[13].mode = SERVO
board.digital[12].mode = SERVO

def set_first_servo(angle):
    board.digital[13].write(angle)
    sleep(0.015)

def set_second_servo(angle):
    board.digital[12].write(angle)
    sleep(0.015)

a, b = True, True
while a:
    for position in range(0, 135):
        set_first_servo(position)

    a = False

while b:
    for position in range(135, 0, -1):
        set_second_servo(position)

    b = False

board.exit()
```

Assuming your second one works that would be the only difference I see.

Comment: If I swap the code I'm gonna get two servos spinning in other direction. The for loops determine which way it spins and how far.

Comment: My mini-project is nearly done .... I just can't seem to figure out why the one servo is spinning twice as much as the other one. The code isn't telling it to do so.

Comment: You may want to check connections and stuff like that because I don't see any issues with code. i usually run my code in Arduino IDE which uses C++so